# Find type of router

Tags: ip, router, ifconfig, nmap

Is there a way to find my type of router from the command line? My IP address is the standard `192.168.1.1` IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `curl http://192.168.1.1` just to get the HTML of the login page.  It probably says on it.

Also, you could use `arp -a` to get the MAC of the router, and then look up the first 6 digits to see what hardware vendor it is.

Comment: the curl doesn't give any useful information, but I got this from `arp -a`: